# Error merging Info.plist in MonoDevelop / MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I just upgraded to the latest versions of MonoDevelop and MonoTouch. Now, when I try to build even an empty iPhone monotouch project, I get the following error:

```
Error merging Info.plist: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

I am a newbie iPhone/monotouch developer, and I have no idea what this might mean. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. I resolved it by uninstalling Xcode 4 and installing the latest version of Xcode 3. I couldn't find anything that definitively said that Xcode 4 was not supported, but it appears to be causing this error.

Comment: This seems to still be the case with the Xcode 4 GM seed. Hopefully there will be an update to fix this in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

The bug was fixed

https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=678530

Edit: 
Here my blog that I did to get around all the issues of using current monotouch on Lion. 
http://joemele.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/monotouch-and-lion/

Answer (score 0):

Try this link.  Just reinstall in the order specified.  It worked for me after seeing the same error during compilation.  You just need the newest iPhone SDK, and so on...

http://monotouch.net/DownloadTrial